# How to change vim colorscheme to point to different directory

Tags: vim

I'm wondering whether I can change 'colorscheme' to point to different directory.(rather than default) since I want to set my all my color schemes in vimrc file with my own directory.

In My MacOS, the default directory are in `/usr/local/share/vim/vim80/colors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to put colorschemes in `~/.vim/colors/`.

Create that directory if it doesn't exist and stay away from `/usr/local/share/vim/`.

Answer (score 1):

As @romainl pointed out, keep your hands off the system-wide directories. Just because Vim's default stuff gets installed under `/usr/local/share/vim`, this doesn't mean that your personal extensions and customizations should be in there as well. You'll provoke problems when upgrading or reinstalling Vim.

If the suggested default location (`~/.vim/colors/`) doesn't suit you, you can add additional directories to `'runtimepath'` (early enough; i.e. in your `~/.vimrc`). For colorschemes, the direct directory has to be `colors`, though. To work around *that*, you'd have to use filesystem links to create an alias.

Comment: It doesn't seem that your proposed solution with updating the 'runtimepath' option works. I am setting it with --cmd command option when launching vim, so that 'runtimepath' option gets updates before execution of VIMRC. Nevertheless the search for colorscheme doesn't look neither in that new folder, nor in its  'colors' subfolder.

I also don't understand where does this restriction of the preexecution come from, what does that add in comparison with updating the 'rtp' option value with a new folder and executing :colorcheme command in runtime?